# R blogdown new_site() throws error

Tags: r, blogdown

If I try to run `blogdown::new_site()` I get an error message I suspect being a linux/windows conversion problem of slashes maybe?

```
blogdown::new_site()
Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in D:\Documents\Blog.

Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/, or
   create your own with the "hugo new theme <THEMENAME>" command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new <SECTIONNAME>\<FILENAME>.<FORMAT>".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.zip'
Content length 119078 bytes (116 KB)
downloaded 116 KB

Error in gsub(tmpdir, ".", zipdir) : 
  invalid regular expression '.\3aec55bc496d', reason 'Invalid back reference'
```

Don't quite get what's going on there... I the command on an empty directory and tied it via Rstudio also trying a different template `gcushen/hugo-academic` which caused the same error message...

I'm running R on a windows machine an all packages are up to date I believe...

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] blogdown_0.5.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 bookdown_0.7   tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.18    knitr_1.20     xfun_0.1
```

Comment: Hi @mhwh, thanks for the issue report. In the future, feel free to report this kind of issue on [blogdown's Github issue tracker](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown). I've submitted [PR #276 to fix this](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/pull/276). In the meantime, you can use the CRAN version of blogdown or the version prior to the change that introduced the bug by running `devtools::install_github("rstudio/blogdown@051efcacf")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this was indeed a bug in blogdown tracing back to differences in how Windows and Unix handle slashes in path names (or more specifically, differences in how `tempfile()` and `utils::unzip()` handle slashes in their output on Windows).

The issue should now be fixed as of version 0.5.10 of blogdown, which you can install using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/blogdown")`.